# Update query with multiple tables doesn't work

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update a table in MySQL with data from another table.

```
UPDATE KassaticketRegels
SET soort = (SELECT t3.benaming 
         FROM KassaticketRegels AS t1 INNER JOIN Diensten AS t2 ON t1.dienst = t2.id INNER JOIN DienstGroepen AS t3 ON t2.dienstGroep = t3.id
        WHERE t1.id = KassaticketRegels.id)
```

When i simulate the query, it gives me 304 matched rows.
[image]

But when i press go, i get the error "#1093 - Table 'KassaticketRegels' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data".

How can i solve this?

Comment: i think your query for getting the value is returning more than one row so you are getting that error.   try adding...  (Select Top 1 ....)  or a Distict so you dont return multiple rows.   You can also try getting the value first into a variable then do the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your code  seems you need  an update on inner join

```
UPDATE KassaticketRegels t1
INNER JOIN Diensten AS t2 ON t1.dienst = t2.id 
INNER JOIN DienstGroepen AS t3 ON t2.dienstGroep = t3.id
set t1.soort = t3.benaming
```